# Clear Console in Java

Tags: java, console

Is there any way to clear the Console?

(I.e. all the output of my class and the output of everything outputted from other programs run before, not always Java)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979383/java-clear-the-console

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/606086/how-do-you-clear-the-java-console

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The process of clearing a console is going to be VERY device dependent (i.e. Windows cmd is going to be very different than a VT100 or Linux xterm. You would probably need something like [Curses for Java](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javacurses/).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing to the console have you tried logging the info you need from your app to a separate file instead of the console?