# How to clear console in Java - Eclipse SDK

Tags: java

I've searched far and wide, but haven't found something that works... 
There HAS to be a way!!! So, what I need is a code that clears the console in Eclipse (makes it blank). And NO, not printing 50 blank lines, CLEARING IT!

I found this:

```
Import import java.io.Console;

public void ClearConsole() {
            Console console = System.console();        
            if (console == null)
                    System.out.println("Couldn't get Console object !");
            console.clear();
    }
```

But it gives me an error: "*The method clear() is undefined for the type Console*"

Comment: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=122429

Comment: Sorry, but clear() method is not defined for java.io.Console http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Console.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java: Clear the console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979383/java-clear-the-console)

Comment: Finally someone posts this question. I've also been searching for the answer to this question far and wide.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Eclipse tool you can clear the console panel by *right clicking* + *clear* but not in Java.

Console is a log tool, it cannot be cleared for administration security.

Comment: The OP is looking for a way to do it programmatically. You can also click on the little grey cross on the upper-right corner of the Eclipse console to clear it :)

Comment: @Jerome  As OP told about Eclipse you give the laziest solution.

Answer (score 14):

I may be late with my answer, but here is what I managed to do (and it worked for me):

I created my console based on this tutorial http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_write_to_the_console_from_a_plug-in%3F , and modified the findConsole method to look like this:

```
private MessageConsole findConsole(String name) {

      ConsolePlugin plugin = ConsolePlugin.getDefault();
      IConsoleManager conMan = plugin.getConsoleManager();

      IConsole[] existing = conMan.getConsoles();
      //if console exists, clear it 
      for (int i = 0; i < existing.length; i++)
          if (name.equals(existing[i].getName())){
              ((MessageConsole) existing[i]).clearConsole(); //this is the important part
              return myConsole;
          }

      myConsole = new MessageConsole(name, null);
      conMan.addConsoles(new IConsole[]{myConsole});
      return myConsole;
   }
```

So, in the listener of some other button/control/whatever, I have:

```
myConsole = findConsole(ASIO_RECORD_OUTPUT);
myConsoleOut = myConsole.newMessageStream();
```

and whenever that piece of code gets executed, my console is cleared. Hope it helps.

edit: Forgot to mention, I did this when creating an RCP application!

Comment: You need to show the import statements that go with this question or else its a lot of impossible guesswork.