# how to clear console in java (using eclipse)

Tags: java, console

I need to clear my console and print other
other Question not help me I check very ways but I cant
I using java
and use

```
System.out.flush();
```

and

```
runtime....
```

Comment: You want to clear the console programmatically ? Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10509476/how-to-clear-console-in-java-eclipse-sdk

Comment: I am test it but cant

Comment: If you can see console window then you can use "ClearConsole" button. It is fourth on the left at top of window. It looks like file with a cross icon on top of it.