# What does it mean when this code is "System Dependent"?

Tags: java, console

I am asking regarding this post: [How to Clear Console: Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979383/java-clear-the-console)

The accepted answer is for clearing the console in Java is:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cls");
```

However, the poster mentioned that this code will be "system dependent". What does the poster mean by this?

(my rep does not allow me to comment on the post).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means that the command won't work on all systems.  `cls` is a command to clear a command window in Windows.  But in Unix, for example, that's not a defined command.

```
$ cls
ksh: cls:  not found
```

That Java code depends on a `cls` command being available.

Comment: So essentially, Java utilizes the OS's commands to clear its own console? So is the Java console an "extension" of the OS console?

Comment: No, this Java code runs an external (to Java) process called "cls", which happens to clear the console in Windows (the console is not owned by Java).

Comment: Right, I come from computer hardware and "system" has a much different meaning. Excuse my newbiness :p

Answer (score 2):

It means that the command is reliant on the current platform to support it.  For example `ls` is a Linux/Unix command, which won't run on Windows, unless you actually have a `ls` program installed.  Equally `dir` is Windows based command.

This makes the statement "System Dependent", restricting it's execution ability to a single (family) of platforms...

Answer (score 2):

Most likely because `cls` is a Windows/DOS command, and wouldn't work on other operating systems.

For example, in a Windows console, you'd clear your screen like so:

```
C:\>cls
```

On, say, Unix, you'd use the `clear` command:

```
$ clear
```

Answer (score 1):

It means it will only work on certain platforms. `cls` is a command specific to Windows platforms. The command will not work on Unix/Linux systems for example where the equivalent [`clear`](http://www.linux.org/threads/linux-command-clear.4196/) command is used to clear the screen

Answer (score 0):

System dependent means that it won't work on some platforms. `cls` will only work on Windows.