# Scala - flushing the std out

Tags: scala, io

Can you suggest me to clear the std out ? I making something similar to progress bar on std out (flushing the terminal screen after new data really helps )

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979383/java-clear-the-console) are some ideas for Java. Execute a shell process (platform dependent) or perhaps use JLine.