# text base programs in java

Tags: java, text-based

i want to create a terminal application in java, but i don't know how to replace text lines that are already printed (kind of "edit the lines that already printed"). `\r` only returns to the beginning of the last line, and i want to display a 2 dimensional grid.
this is a sample for what i want to print:

```
System.out.println("################");
System.out.println("#--------------#");
System.out.println("#--------------#");
System.out.println("################");


System.out.println("\r################");
System.out.println("#-------X------#");
System.out.println("#--------------#");
System.out.println("################");
```

Comment: Have you tried using `\b`...alot...

Comment: You can clear the screen, or use terminal escape sequences to move the cursor around. Also look into `curses`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should try JLine library. It provides many userful functions for command line applications. http://jline.sourceforge.net/javadoc/

Answer (score 0):

Using `System.out.println` whatever text is printed to the console is already flushed and cannot be edited. What you can do is you can clear the console and reprint using a fresh set Sys Outs. But for a graphical application I would suggest you have a look at `JAVA AWT` which will give you functions like `paint() and repaint()` and other rich UI functions.

For clearing the console you can refer to this: [clear console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979383/java-clear-the-console)

For JAVA AWT: [AWT tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/basic2d/)

Comment: I know to use awt, i just got loved in the terminal when started working with linux.

Comment: Then you can write your own repaint method where you clear the console and reprint the updated output.

Comment: I took a look at other stackoverflow questions, and found this: runtime.getRuntime().exec("cls"); that should clear the terminal.

Comment: It is OS dependent though. it will surely work for windows. Also you can have a look at JLine library as @faisalbhagat suggested. it has methods like clearconsole etc..