# How do i resolve method Overlapping in java/Processing

Tags: java, methods, processing

I have two methods/function in a class, called, Qestion1 and Question2, i want it in such a way that after the user has answered Question one correctly, the Question 2 method is called. Whenever i call the method 2, it displays both of them together instead exiting the first method first. Here's a dummy code to illustrate what i'm saying:

```
void Question1()  {
 String question="What is the capital of England?";
 String Answer="London";

if(Answer=='London')
 {
Question2();
 }
 }


 void Question2()  {
 String question="What is the capital of California?";
 String Answer="Sacramento";

  if(Answer=='Sacramento')
     {
 Question3();
  }
   }
```

Pls, this question is in no way related to that other question. Pls peruse the thread again.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking... What's wrong with the example code?

Comment: It displays both questions at the same time when asked to display just Question2.

Comment: What do you mean? Do you mean you want to clear the console before displaying Question 2?

Comment: That's exactly what i want to do.

Comment: Mind updating your question for clarity then? There's [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979383/java-clear-the-console) for a start