# Adding and removing text from the console in Java

Tags: java

Have searched this quite a bit and haven't found anything.

So, we know to print text it is `System.out.print` or `println` or whatever your needs are. You can also use `System.console()` and call methods on that.

However, I see applications which change output which they have added to the screen. For example, removing things which are no longer relevant after they are finished. How is this done in Java?

Comment: CLEAR THE CONSOLE AND REPRINT WHAT EVER IS VALID ...

Comment: @Aeshang so the entire console must be cleared and all valid text reprinted?

Comment: Yes I cannot think of another way to accomplish what you need ...

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/q/2979383/1085586 to clear all the console http://stackoverflow.com/a/14410352/1085586 .

Comment: [Java Curses](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javacurses/) can do it.

Comment: @Elliot thanks for the link but I'd rather use the \b backspace character than have a dependency

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can delete text by using the backspace character `\b`.  For example:

```
System.out.print("\b");
```

An example:

```
public class Test {

    public static final String[] frames = {"|", "/", "-", "\\"};

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println();

        for (int ctr = 0; ctr < 50; ctr++) {
            System.out.print(frames[ctr % frames.length]);
            Thread.sleep(250);
            System.out.print("\b");
        }
    }
}
```

Note, however, that this may not work in the Eclipse console, but will work outside of Eclipse.

Comment: Good answer, thanks for that. I wasn't looking forward to clearing the console and tracking the things I wanted to keep to reprint them.

Comment: \b will erase only last character ... if you want to erase something in the middle then it won't be useful ...

Comment: \r also works on most consoles - takes your cursor to start of line

Comment: @Aeshang it's easier to clear a single line and then reprint what you want using \b that to clear the entire console and reprint a load of stuff though