# How do I clear the console in Java

Tags: java, console

How do I clear the console in Java? This is my code but it doesn't do anything.

```
switch (commandTyped.toUpperCase()) {
        case "I":
            final String ANSI_CLS = "\u001b[2J";
            final String ANSI_HOME = "\u001b[H";
            System.out.print(ANSI_CLS + ANSI_HOME);
            System.out.flush();
            inventory.check();
            break;


    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Clearing the console (if it can be done at all) will be intimately tied to the particular Java execution environment you're using.

Answer (score -3):

You can use:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cls");
```

it will clear the console

Comment: ["This command will not work, for two reasons"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33379766/3788176)

Comment: Did you try this? It usually doesn't work, because `exec()` isn't running its argument in a command line interpreter. It's also specific to Windows.

Comment: You can use ASCII Escape codes also to clear check this one

System.out.print("\033[H\033[2J");

Comment: That didn't work. Thanks for trying to help though!

Comment: @Agha, that one didn't work either.