# Clearing Console with a Plugin or separate console in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there any plugin I can use in java ECLIPSE that supports clearing the console in the code, not a command. For example if I did clearConsonle(); (I would make it a method) it would clear the console. I want to type this in my code not use a command.

Or a plugin that creates an new console that can be cleared?

I have looked for existing plugins in java but had no luck finding any. I was wondering if you all had any plugins you knew of.

I would print \n a lot of times but then the console gets laggy. Is there anyway I could fix this?

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979383/java-clear-the-console) here on SO help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: Clear the console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979383/java-clear-the-console)