# Java - Clearing screen clears printed text after its execution

Tags: java, methods

Inside of method

```
new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "cls").inheritIO().start();

System.out.println("Press enter to continue...");
```

Back to main method Switch

```
System.out.println("Blah blah blah");
```

In both cases my program clears everything, leaving no text to tell the user what to do, but instead a blank terminal. I've also tried creating its own method, but it will still clear text before and after its execution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: Clear the console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979383/java-clear-the-console)

Answer (score 2):

You need to wait for the external process to finish. You can do that with [`Process.waitFor()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor--). Like,

```
Process p = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "cls").inheritIO().start();
p.waitFor(); // <-- wait for p to finish
```

Answer (score -2):

For people with similar future problems, use the answer from above, then put throws IOException, InterruptedException from the method it is called and every method higher up.

Comment: Instead of posting a new answer that is the same as the answer suggested 11 hours ago, you should accept that answer.

Comment: Also, remember that positional words like "above" don't work in SO.