# Is there a way to clear Eclipse console in C++?

Tags: c++, eclipse

I'm developing a C++ application that interacts with user. I want to clear the screen in some situations. I found a command called system("CLS"). *By the way, I'am working on Windows.* But, the command works only if I am running the program from CMD or PowerShell. The thing I want is to clear the Eclipse IDE console.
ECLIPSE VERSION: 4.3.2 Kepler *(a little bit old)*

Comment: Many terminal emulators usually implement a subset of the control codes used for the old [VT100 terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VT100). See e.g. [here](http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm) for a reference of some of them. Try the *erase screen* code and print it and see what happens.

Comment: Doesn't work :(

Comment: Unfortunately, also the [_ANSI Escape in Console_](https://mihai-nita.net/2013/06/03/eclipse-plugin-ansi-in-console/) plug-in does not support the clear screen command. There might be another plugin for this, but I guess such a plugin doesn't exist (because when developing, in most cases it is useful to see the entire console output).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java: Clear the console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979383/java-clear-the-console)