# Is it possible to remove new lines from the console in Java?

Tags: java, console

So I have been trying out different ways to represent information in the console and I have noticed printing `\b` doesn't remove newlines in the console.

Here is an example:

```
System.out.println("ggg");
System.out.print("\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b");
```

shows up as `ggg`.

Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: Why would \b remove new lines?

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Java: Clear the console](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2979383)?

Comment: Which console is this? Windows cmd.exe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"/b" just omit a character from the console; the problem is that in your code the "ggg" line will be printed and thew following "/b"s will be printed on a new line in the console, they can not affect the prior line.
You need to use "/b" on the same line.
Visit http://www.java2s.com/Code/Python/String/EscapeCodesbtnar.htm to grasp java escape codes.

Comment: thank you for clarifying, so to make sure I understand correctly, once the console moves on to the next line there is no way to go back to the previous line to change it.

Comment: exactly, as others mentioned \b can not remove characters from prior lines from console. once you printed something on the console you need to use console commands to manipulate it.

Answer (score 0):

\b doesn't remove new lines, depending on the OutputStream, it **may** remove a character. For example, try

```java
System.out.println("ggg\b");
```

Comment: I have tried doing it on the same line and it does work, thanks for your feedback but that wasn't my question