# How to clean the output of netbeans in a "console" application?

Tags: java, c#

I am migrating code from C # to JAVA in Netbeans for class work and I have a little problem with this; in C# I use `Console.Clear` to clean command prompt and make it look readable and very interactive, but in Netbeans it doesn't have a function to clean its output, what it does have is the "Clean" with the shortcut "Control + L", I found that the "Robot" class could be used to "automate" it in a certain sense but I don't know why but the normal sequence like being canceled or crashed, nothing appears after applying a "System.out.println".

Then I would like to know if it can be done in another way (except run it by cmd using the command "java -jar path")

Comment: Maybe [Java: Clear the console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979383/java-clear-the-console)?

Comment: Without going into trying to get Ansi commends to work, you could simply create a loop which prints a number of empty lines

Answer (score 0):

**1** - First solution, sadly, on `Windows`, there is no clean way of doing so. You'll need to use a load of `System.out.println("");` in order to do so.

**2** - The second solution, on `Unix systems`, there is an `ANSI Escape Sequence` that accomplishes that, and it's `\033[2J` once printed this will `clear` the console.

**3** - The third solution. Install a plugin for `NetBeans` to make the console support `ANSI sequences` which would allow you to use colors and the `\033[2J` method.

**4** - Finally, there's a `Java library` for that purpose that detects the current console/terminal and allows you to interact with it like you would with any other ones. Its called [jcurses](https://sourceforge.net/projects/javacurses/)

Comment: Mmm no way and I have to leave it like that, text on text, but thanks.

Comment: Elaborate a bit more so I could give you further help.