# Java - How to use \r for multiple lines?

Tags: java, string, shell, command-line, printing

So if I have a basic terminal app in Java with three printed lines like,

```
Progress: 30%
Total items = 3
Name next item here -> :
```

How would you edit the 1st or 2nd line? I tried using `\r` but that seems to only work on the current line. Is there a special function or escape character that would work?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code

Comment: Under Windows `\r\n`, under Linux `\n` - so you probably had a remaining `\n`. In regex you should use `"\\R"` which captures any line break.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure `\r` only works with one line.

You could always clear the whole console  ([Java: Clear the console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979383/java-clear-the-console))

Comment: The "cls" command above does not work for me on Windows, but the `clearScreen()` solution further down that same SO post does clear console.