# Is there a way to replace output in eclipse while a program is still running?

Tags: java

Let me clarify, I am currently finishing up a terminal chess program I'm writing. The way it works now is that after every turn the board is printed again. This looks sloppy though and I would prefer if there were some way for the board to just be replaced/updated each turn. If this cant be done in eclipse are there other IDE's that can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do this, you cannot actually do this in the terminal. For this, consider using [JFrames](https://www.codejava.net/java-se/swing/jframe-basic-tutorial-and-examples). JFrames open up an actual panel on your screen which shows the content.

Comment: Ok thought that might be the case, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

its not really an IDE thing as much as it is an OS thing:

```
public static void clearScreen() {  
    System.out.print("\033[H\033[2J");  
    System.out.flush();  
}
```

Read this:
ref: [Java: Clear the console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979383/java-clear-the-console)