# Is there a way to clear the IntelliJ output terminal?

Tags: java, if-statement, intellij-idea

I've written some Sysout lines, and I want to create an if else where the output console is cleared?

```
if(pass.length() < 8){
        System.out.println("");
//now I would like the output terminal to be cleared
    }else {
        System.out.println("");
    }
```

Prepared to answer any questions. Feel free to edit. If this is a previous answered question, please let me know, I can't seem to find anything.

Comment: It doesn't seem possible to me. What you can try as a workaround is to print 100 empty lines. It will clear the console.

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ IDEA console is not a real terminal, so there is no command to clear it from your Java code.

Comment: Alright - what would you recommend I do? Run it  from cmd?

Comment: Yes. And read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979383/java-clear-the-console

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do that with [Grep Console plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7125-grep-console).

But only for a Console - and you are talking about console, not Terminal that is used for JS/NPM/GoLand and others.
[image: config]