# Java: Clear console of NetBeans, through my program

Tags: java, netbeans, command-line

I want to clear the console output of the NetBeans console. We can clear it manually by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.

Is it possible to do this programmatically, in Java?

Thank you very much

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11818991/clear-the-console-programmatically-in-java

Answer (score 0):

I think that it's not so simple.

The Netbeans console is not really a full system console.

I'd see a proper option - like getting the console reference using the Netbeans RPC binding, but your application would need to run as a Netbeans plugin or bundle. (so - don't do that, keep it simple)

For a shortcut (workaround) - you may try to use java.awt.Robot class to send a keyRelease event (Ctrl+L) while being focused in the console (effectively sending the Ctrl+L event to the focused component)

Answer (score 0):

This is a poor solution because it doesn't actually clear anything, but it does push it out of the way to hopefully make it more readable.

System.out.print("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");

add or subtract "\n" to lengthen or shorten it depending on the size of the console window.

Comment: This looks more like a comment to the other answer rather than a new answer.